# Scheduled Reminders - differentiating by contribution type

Tags: civicontribute, scheduled-reminders

In the User Guide it says that you can set up scheduled reminders to 'send to contacts who made a contribution of the selected financial type(s) with any combination of contribution statuses.'

However in the Scheduled Reminder interface if I select Contribution as the Activity I can see a drop-down menu for Status, but no way to specify the financial type.

I want an email to go out when contributions of financial type x, y etc are completed.

[image]

Any  help appreciated!

CiviCRM 4.6.24

Drupal

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  This looks like a good question.  You could make it better by editing it to include the version of CiviCRM and the CMS (e.g. Drupal, WordPress or Joomla) that you are using.  Some answers may be different depending on the version. Also a screenshot could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have selected 'Activity' as the 'Entity' in the first drop down list.  Instead of 'Activity' you should select 'Contribution Type'.  You will then be able to choose the relevant financial types and contribution status (Ctrl-click to select more than one).

See the screenshot below (taken from the CiviCRM 4.7 demo site):
[image]

It sounds like you have already looked at the User Guide, but for the benefit of others here is the relevant page for more details: [Scheduled Reminders](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/scheduled-reminders/)

Please note that this functionality was added in CiviCRM 4.7.  It is not available in earlier versions of CiviCRM.  As you are using CiviCRM 4.6 perhaps you could consider upgrading to 4.7?

Comment: If I don't have a Contribution Type Entity, does that mean I need to install something?

Comment: I have Event Type, Event Name, Membership, Event Template, and Contact

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM are you using?  This may have changed between versions.

Comment: @TomALT this is why we ask for folks to please post their CiviCRM version :)  "Contribution Type" won't be available unless you're using CiviCRM 4.7.

Comment: Thanks both, and apologies - you can probably tell I am a neophyte. We have CiviCRM 4.6.24 so I guess that explains it. I don't suppose you know a good way to achieve the same result? I know it can be done with CiviRules but it seems like using a hammer to crack a nut. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @TomALT I've updated your question with the version of CiviCRM.  Are you able to upgrade to CivICRM 4.7?  It seems like that would solve your problem.